# Como atribuir valor a uma variável PHP usando JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma tabela com vários registros e, assim que determinado link referente ao registro é clicado, seria aberta uma janela modal com mais informações referentes a ele.

Link:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="' . $res->codigoLO . '"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

O seguinte script pega um valor que é enviado por parâmetro quando se clica no link e o seta em um input presente na janela modal. Na verdade, gostaria que ao invés de esse valor ser colocado em input, fosse atribuído diretamente à uma variável PHP também presente na janela modal.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
            $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="bookId"]').val(bookId);
              });
    </script>
```

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você não consegue setar variáveis em PHP pelo Javascript.
PHP roda do lado do servidor, enquanto javascript roda no browser (lado do cliente)

Comment: Complementando o que disse o @Callebe: quando o JavaScript executa, o PHP já terminou seu serviço faz tempo, não existem mais variáveis PHP nesse contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquise sobre o Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript and XML). Há várias maneiras como podemos utiliza-lo, e um desses jeitos permite passar valores para outro arquivo (PHP, no seu caso) e chama-lo para dentro da página atual sem precisar recarregar a página e é muito utilizado quando precisamos manipular modais. Aqui está um exemplo de um código tirado da documentação do jQuery quanto a utilização do Ajax porém utilizando a biblioteca jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }})
.done(function( msg ) { 
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); 
});
```

E o retorno das outras informações (atributos) do registro para o lado do cliente poderia ser feito utilizando JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), um código que utilizo para converter um objeto, array ou variável para JSON no PHP é:

```
echo json_encode($lista_json)
```

E isso retornaria um ou vários elementos para o JavaScript para manipular na página conforme nossas exigências.

Alguns links interessantes sobre estes assuntos:

jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

W3Schools AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

W3Schools JSON: http://www.w3schools.com/json/